# Using has_text with non-English characters

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to click a link on a page using Playwright for Python that has non-English characters in its text:

`page.locator("a", has_text="Grégoire").click()`

hangs and gives the error:

waiting for selector "a >> :scope:has-text("Gr\u00e9goire")"

Note that this code works for links with English names on the same page. How do you use has_text with non-English characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:has-text` [text selector](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/selectors#text-selector):

```
page.locator('a:has-text("Grégoire")').click()
```